# Make calculations for records inside pagination, django

Tags: python, django

I want to calculate the sum of two records but only inside the pagination.

```
class MacaListView(ListView):
    model = Maca
    paginate_by = 20

        def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
            context = super(MacaListView, self).get_context_data(object_list=None, **kwargs)
            maca = Maca.objects.all()
            for i in range(0, maca.count()):
                maca1 = Maca.objects.get(maca[i].id)
                maca1.number = maca.number + 1

                maca1.save()
```

This will go to every single record and do the logic. I want the logic to be executed for only records in pagination (do calculate for only 20 records)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try it?
in here we get the current page number and slice queryset to get only needed elements.

```
class MacaListView(ListView):
    model = Maca
    paginate_by = 20

        def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):

            context = super(MacaListView, self).get_context_data(object_list=None, **kwargs)
            page =  int(self.request.GET.get('page', 1))
            maca = Maca.objects.all()[(page-1)*self.paginate_by:self.paginate_by]
            for i in range(0, maca.count()):
                maca = Maca.objects.get(maca[i].id)
                maca.number = maca.number + 1

                maca.save()
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. But please convert the page variable into integer because it is raising an error!

Comment: great, thanks...